# Jquery/Ajax/JavaScript Time Count Down Non-Stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone give me Jquery function for **Time Count Down** , but work like this.

Time every 15 minutes (without stop).

When time is 0, do some Ajax update function and auto start again (Without click or refresh by myself)

**The time like** (TimeCountDown = TimeNow - (TimeNow+15minuts)).

I just can't find functions like this, and i don't know how to work with time.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You couldn't have looked too hard because [this is the first Google result](http://blog.smalldo.gs/2013/12/create-simple-countdown/)  and does almost exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MikeC C I looked good, where is Your result do Non-Stop ? Just Time Count Down and after do some msg. For shop function but not for me.

Comment: If you want it to go on forever, just restart it when it's done.

Comment: @MikeC its not ease. to restart with new datetime for next game, not with numbers. Because in the future i wanna give datetime from MYSQL DATABASE.

Comment: I think you need a more fundamental understand of JavaScript before continuing because working with numbers is probably the easiest thing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var _TimerCount = 15;
    var _Timer = setInterval(function(){
    TimerCountDown();
},6000);

    function TimerCountDown(){
    if(_TimerCount !=0){
       _TimerCount -=1;
    }
    else{
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var _DateString = currentdate.getDate() + " " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    _TimerCount = 15;
    $.get("C# CODE FILE HERE eg. MyFile.ashx",{_DateTime:_DateString }).done(function(response){
     //Your Response CODE HERE 
     alert(response);
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do this with DateTime ? Without just number 15. I must datatime, for take results from MYSQL )))

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you are wanting to retrieve data from sql every 15 minutes in return with the Date Time Now. Is This Correct ?

Comment: Every 15 minutes (should update the data and then display the result), the time you need to see (how much is left), and all this with SQL/MYSQL DATABASE

Comment: I will edit this post shortly with the updates you need.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I will wait )))

Comment: Please review the changes. I can assist with generic handlers as well if needed.

Comment: thanks, i will check you function soon. thanks again ))) I will check  this too http://jsfiddle.net/m27tU/ just find.

Comment: You should mark the answer if you found it correct OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do.

I think you want something like this:

```
var timeOut = function() {
****Whatever you want the code to do every 15 minutes****
};

var main = function() {
    setInterval(timeOut, 900000);
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Note: time is in miliseconds so 1 second = 1000

JSFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/552nu/1/`

Comment: This is very nice, can you do example in jsfiddle.net with show time running ? thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/552nu/1/

concept from `http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp` - steal shamelessly :)